# How do you use sans-serif fonts with typst?

Tags: typst

Neither, Arial, Helvetica, or sans-serif, works.

```
#set text(font: (
  "sans-serif",
  "Helvetica",
  "Arial"
))

Some text.
```

[image: some text not sans serif]
So what gives? How can I make my text sans-serif, which fonts are actually supported?

Comment: I can partly reproduce the issue, with https://github.com/typst/typst/releases/download/v0.3.0/typst-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.xz I get sans serif output on Ubuntu (it has chosen Arial MT). However, if I remove both named font hints and leave only `sans-serif` then it doesn't work. So maybe you don't have either font installed?

Comment: Im on the web app.

Comment: Most likely the web app runs on some Linux variant, so Helvetica and Arial will not be available there. You could try DejaVu Sans or Liberation Sans, maybe Noto Sans or FreeSans.

Comment: Use the command `typst fonts` for a list of the available fonts. Depending on your operating system, Helvetica or Arial might not be installed by default.

Comment: Even for the web app, the compiler runs on your computer and can access a set of web fonts we provide. System fonts are not available due to browser sandboxing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the list of supported fonts by clicking on the "Ag" button in the toolbar if you are using the web app.

Try

```
#set text(font: "TeX Gyre Heros")
```

or

```
#set text(font: "Inter")
```

for Helvetica-like fonts that come with the web app. If you'd like to bring your own fonts instead, you can upload a `.ttf`,  `.ttc`, `.otf`, or `.otc` file into your project.

If you are using the local compiler instead, Typst will make all fonts of your system available. You can list them using the `typst fonts` command on the command line.